# Why doesn't my sdl2 linking work even though i specified all libraries?

Tags: c++, mingw, sdl-2

I don't know why my code doesn't link.

Gcc Command:

```
g++.exe -g -std=c++17 main.cpp -ISDL2\include -o main.exe -LSDL2\lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

main.cpp:

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

int main() {

    SDL_Delay(5000);

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
In function `main':
main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried many different orders of the parameters.

I also tried to reinstall / use other mingw / sdl2 releases.

Comment: Read the linked question. Probably you're using x32 libs with x64 compiler, or vice versa.